# select() call getting stuck

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, udp

I am trying to create a stop-n-wait protocol for file transfer. The client sends a msg while server sends an acknowledgement for the msg. Each msg has a sequence 0/1. When trying to implement                 retval = select(s+1, &set, NULL, NULL, &tv), the code gets stuck at this line and doesn't go forward. I am trying to use select so as to timeout recvfrom() after some time.

client code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define BUFLEN 512
#define PORT 4445

int state = 0;
int flag = 0;

typedef struct pack1{
    int sq_no;
}ACK_PKT;

typedef struct pack2{
    int sq_no;
    char data[BUFLEN];
}DATA_PKT;

void die(char* s){
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main(){
    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int s, i, slen=sizeof(si_other), retval;
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    char msg[BUFLEN];
    DATA_PKT send_pkt;
    ACK_PKT rcv_ack;
    if((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1)
        die("socket");
    
    struct timeval tv; 
    fd_set set;
    memset((char*)&si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_other.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    
    while(1){
        switch(state){             
            case 2:
                printf("Enter msg 1: ");
            fgets(send_pkt.data, sizeof(send_pkt), stdin);
            send_pkt.sq_no = 1;
            if(sendto(s, &send_pkt, sizeof(send_pkt), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&si_other, slen)==-1)
                die("sendto()");
            state = 3;
            break;
            
        case 3:
            tv.tv_sec = 2;
            FD_ZERO(&set); 
            FD_SET(s, &set);
            printf("coming here atleast\n");
            printf("to timeout = %ld\n", tv.tv_sec);
            retval = select(s+1, &set, NULL, NULL, &tv);
            printf("%d\n", retval);
         if (retval == -1)
             die("error");
         else if (retval == 0){
            printf("packet lost, resending\n");
            if(sendto(s, &send_pkt, sizeof(send_pkt), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&si_other, slen)==-1)
                    die("sendto()");
                state = 3;
                printf("msg sent\n");
            break;
         }
         else
             if(recvfrom(s, &rcv_ack, sizeof(rcv_ack), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&si_other, &slen)==-1)
                 die("receiving error");

                if(rcv_ack.sq_no==1){
                    printf("Received ack seq no. %d\n", rcv_ack.sq_no);
                    state = 2;
                }
                break;
        }
    } 
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

server code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFLEN 512
#define PORT 4445

typedef struct pack1{
    int sq_no;
}ACK_PKT;

typedef struct pack2{
    int sq_no;
    char data[BUFLEN];
}DATA_PKT;

void die(char* s){
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main(){
    struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;
    int s, i, slen=sizeof(si_other), recv_len;
    //char buf[BUFLEN];
    char msg[BUFLEN];
    ACK_PKT ack_pkt;
    DATA_PKT rcv_pkt;
    if((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1)
        die("socket");
    printf("sokcket created\n");
    
    memset((char*)&si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));
    memset((char*)&si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    
    if(bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me))==-1)
        die("bind");
    printf("socket bound\n");
    
    int state = 1;
    while(1){
        switch(state){
            case 1:
                printf("Waiting for packet 1 from sender...\n");    
                ack_pkt.sq_no = 1;
                flag = 1;
                if(flag==0){
                    if(recvfrom(s, &rcv_pkt, sizeof(rcv_pkt), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&si_other, &slen)==-1)
                        die("recvfrom()");
                    printf("packet lost\n");
                    state = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    if(recvfrom(s, &rcv_pkt, sizeof(rcv_pkt), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&si_other, &slen)==-1)
                        die("recvfrom()");
                    if(rcv_pkt.sq_no==1){
                        printf("Packet received with seq no. %d and Packet content is = %s\n", rcv_pkt.sq_no, rcv_pkt.data); 
                    }
                    if(sendto(s, &ack_pkt, sizeof(ack_pkt), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&si_other, slen)==-1)
                        die("sendto()");             
                    state = 1;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }    
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

this is how I am initializing select -

```
struct timeval tv; 
fd_set set;
tv.tv_sec = 2;
FD_ZERO(&set); 
FD_SET(s, &set);
retval = select(s+1, &set, NULL, NULL, &tv);
```

Comment: you're saying `select` blocks indefinitely even though you've specified the 2 second timeout? One thing to consider... you're only initializing the `.tv_sec` field, leaving `.tv_nsec` uninitialized. This is supposed to be [0, 999999999], but it is a `long` which can be 8 bytes, so maybe it's some huge count of nanoseconds making your timeout much larger than 2 seconds? Try setting `.tv_nsec = 0`

Comment: In select() first parameter should be 2 = number of socket in set plus 1. It can work if luckily s==1

Comment: The client doesn't seem to ever send anything because the state remains 0 and none of the switch cases handles it. Am I missing something?

Comment: @yano thanks! that was the issue I was missing.

Comment: @Zoso sorry, I actually edited the code for SO, so forgot to change the state, the state is actually 2, but anyways, the issue is now solved, but thanks anyways.